# Literal &#39; appears in flag panel instead of being escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, user-interface

As you can see, the off-topic page isn't quite right...

[image]

Could this (minor) issue be fixed?

Comment: Quick...Rollback..Rollback....:P

Comment: This can&#39;t be true. Or is it?

Comment: Must...resist...vote...to...close.... I mean I have the dialog open already... Only one...more....click!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were 2 occurrences of this issue: close dialog and flag dialog titles.

I have fixed teh codez.

The patch will be deployed in the next build out.

Comment: Yay, it&#39;s fixed! +1